# How do I get the host/server information in a Docker container?

Tags: docker

I want to get information like Memory Usage, CPU Usage etc of the host in a docker container. I tried using this:

```
$sudo docker -D info
```

But this returns only the number of CPU's and IP address etc. I want the CPU Usage and Memory Usage too.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

For get this informations, you need to use the following command:

```
docker stats <CONTAINER ID>
```